# strcat operation with tabs character not working

Tags: c++

I am tring to convert an integer array `attr` of length `numAttr` to string but separated by tabs `'\t'` using the below code. If `attr[i] = 0`, I add just a tab `'\t'` to `attrStr` so that that field is empty string. If `attr[i] !=0`, I convert the integer to string and add to `attrStr`. But on doing `strcat(attrStr,"\t")`, no tab character is added to the string. Is there anything specific that I am missing? I hope I am using `strcat` operation in the right way though. Below is the code:

```
char *attrStr = new char[len]; strcpy(attrStr,"");
char *buf = new char[buflen]; strcpy(buf,"");
int i = 0;
for (i=0; i<numAttr-1; i++) {
    if (attr[i]!=0) {
        itoa(attr[i],buf,10); 
        strcat(buf,"\t"); 
        strcat(attrStr, buf);
    } else {
        strcpy(buf,"\t"); 
        strcat(attrStr, buf);
    }
}
itoa(attr[i],buf,10); strcat(attrStr, buf);
return attrStr;
```

Comment: Do you have a specific question that we can answer? "Is there anything specific that I am missing?" seems overly broad for this forum.

Comment: Yes, then how to do it? because in the way I have done it, it is not separating the string with tabs. I want the string to be separated by tabs

Comment: Can you please tell me how to accept answers? I don't see any accept answer option. May be becoz I am an unregistered user

Answer (score 2):

Use `std::stringstream` and `std::string`. They will make your life simple and easy.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

std::stringstream ss;
ss << attr[0];
for (i=1; i<numAttr; i++) 
{
    if ( attr[i] )
       ss << "\t" << attr[i];
    else
       ss << "\t"; // If attr[i] = 0, add '\t' to the string (as instructed)
}
std::string s = ss.str();
```

Comment: But in your code, attr[0] is added no matter if it is 0 or not. That is not the case that I am looking for. Though your example is helpful to start with std::string. Thanks

Comment: Is there any way that I can delete trailing tab from std::string?

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, use std::strings. That, formatting, and memory leaks apart, your code looks OKish.

But, how do you know that you don't have tab characters in the string? How are you inspecting it?

Not all IO devices and GUI systems support tabs in the output, so I would look at the char* buffers with a debugger to check if they are really missing.

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems with your code, but in general your code does exactly what it supposed to do. The TAB character is added to the string the way you want it to be added. If you are not seeing it, you must be looking in the wrong place or in the wrong way.

What exactly made you believe that the TAB character is not added?

Comment: yes as I replied to Roddy, I debugged the code thru VS debugger

Comment: @Somnath Chakrabarti: Well, I also ran your code under VS and used the debugger to see whether the TAB characters were there. They were there. Are you sure you are interpreting what you see in the debugger correctly?